# Strange behaviour of the typeid operator -return FALSE always

Tags: c++

This is my part of my code. The question is why using this line return FLASE and i can't get in to his block:
i'm trying to check if my item type is equals to the son.
It's suppose to return true. I see in the debugging it's true also.

```
if ((typeid(Candy) == typeid(sArray[0])) && (typeid(Candy) == typeid(&item)))
```

this is my code:

```
bool Customer::isExistItem(SweetItem& item){

if (Itemsize == 0){
    sArray = new SweetItem*[Itemsize + 1];
    sArray[Itemsize] = &item;
    Itemsize++;

    if ((typeid(Candy) == typeid(sArray[0])) && (typeid(Candy) == typeid(&item))){
        Candy* help1 = dynamic_cast <Candy*> (sArray[0]);
        Candy* help2 = dynamic_cast <Candy*> (&item);

        if (*help1 == *help2){ //The first item in the basket!
            double payment = 0;
            payment += help1->getPrice();
            totalPayment(payment);
        }

        return TRUE;
    }

    else if ((typeid(Cookie*) == typeid(sArray[0])) && (typeid(Cookie*) == typeid(&item))){
        Cookie* help1 = dynamic_cast <Cookie*> (sArray[0]);
        Cookie* help2 = dynamic_cast <Cookie*> (&item);

        if (*help1 == *help2){ //The first item in the basket!
            double payment = 0;
            payment += help1->getPrice();
            totalPayment(payment);
        }

        return TRUE;
    }

    else if ((typeid(IceCream*) == typeid(sArray[0])) && (typeid(IceCream*)   == typeid(&item))){
        IceCream* help1 = dynamic_cast <IceCream*> (sArray[0]);
        IceCream* help2 = dynamic_cast <IceCream*> (&item);

        if (*help1 == *help2){ //The first item in the basket!
            double payment = 0;
            payment += help1->getPrice();
            totalPayment(payment);
        }

        return TRUE;
    }

    else if ((typeid(Cookielida*) == typeid(sArray[0])) &&         (typeid(Cookielida*) == typeid(&item))){
        Cookielida* help1 = dynamic_cast <Cookielida*> (sArray[0]);
        Cookielida* help2 = dynamic_cast <Cookielida*> (&item);

        if (*help1 == *help2){ //The first item in the basket!
            double payment = 0;
            payment += help1->getPrice();
            totalPayment(payment);
        }

        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

this is my == operator that looks ok:

```
bool Customer::operator ==(const SweetItem& other) const{
for (int i = 0; i < Itemsize; i++){
    if (sArray[i] != &other)
        return FALSE;
}
return TRUE;
```

}

please take a look at my code.

Comment: When in doubt, print out the typeid-name, see example here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid

Answer (score 1):

The type of both `sArray[0]` and `&item` is a `SweetItem*` pointer, which is never the same as a `Candy` object.

I guess you want `typeid(*sArray[0])` and `typeid(item)`, to examine the dynamic type of the object rather than a more generically typed pointer.

Comment: Thank you mike! it's ok know :)